# Which Ubuntu-list should be used to give feedback on 11.10 to 12.04 upgrade issues?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, community

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 beta2 via `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` and have identified a few... glitches and issues in the process/script, mostly from an end-user's perspective. There seems to more than one list that might fit in the Ubuntu-devel- or perhaps Ubuntu-qa- or even Ubuntu-desktop- hierarchies.

I know about Launchpad, Brainstorm, BugSquad, etc, but I'm looking for the mailing-list where the people who develop this specific process discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Ubuntu mailing lists page](https://lists.ubuntu.com/)

Both the development and QA lists are there.